# Deleting condition formatting for texts & blanks which may occur at any cell in range(b1:b54)

Tags: excel, vba

The conditional formattiong is applied to the range(B1:B54) which contains numbers, text & blank. Once this is done, I am required to re-colour cells in a column back to default one which are coloured either green or red from conditional formatting.

Can anybody give me small script to either delete the CF for texts & blanks in range(B1:B54).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete_CF()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range


    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change if needed

        'Set the range to loop
        Set rng = .Range("B1:B54")

        'Loop the range
        For Each cell In rng

            With cell
                'Check if cell is empty or not numeric
                If .Value = "" Or Not IsNumeric(.Value) Then
                    .FormatConditions.Delete
                End If
            End With

        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to hear that my code helps. please vote to help others